# Replace all childnodes that have classname attribute in java script

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver for my project. I have a webpage where there are multiple menu items which in turn has sub menu items. I want to replace the classname attribute for all child elements under the nav-left-main div tag with "" (space) so that all elements are visible in the main page to click (instead of navigating to each menu->sub menu)
Basically i want to find all elements with classname under id=main and replace them with ''. How do i do that with JavaScriptExecutor in selenium webdriver?

```
<div id="nav-left-main">
<div>
<a class="left-nav-icons icomoon-icon-users3 " title="Users" href="#Users-tab">
<div id="Users-sub" class="nav-left-subnav">
    <div id="Users-tab" class="hidden-menu">
      <ul class="level3menu">
       <li>
          <i class="cm-icon18 iconfont-arrow-sans-right" style="margin-top:-2px;margin-left:-17px;"></i>
          <a>Users</a>
          <ul class="second-level-hidden-menu" style="margin-left:5px;margin- top:10px;">
          <ul class="second-level-hidden-menu" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:10px;">
          <ul class="second-level-hidden-menu" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:10px;">
       </li>
   </ul>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a id="AdminGroups" class="$item.className" title="" href="cms?action=groupList&pageTitle=Groups">Groups</a>
      </li>
</ul>
<ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don;t have an element with id `main`?

Comment: What about `while (document.getElementsByClassName("second-level-hidden-menu").length > 0) { document.getElementsByClassName("second-level-hidden-menu")[0].removeAttribute("class")}` ? (Okay, I will be the first to admit that I don't write the most efficient JS code)

Comment: @Rajaprabhu..It should be nav-left-main instead of main.

Comment: @skandigraun...There are still many childnodes under the main div tag which has different classname. For example above we have class="nav-left-subnav", class="hidden-menu", class="cm-icon18 iconfont-arrow-sans-right etc along with class="second-level-hidden-menu". I need to replace all class names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
var main_div = document.getElementById("nav-left-main");
var all_childs = main_div.getElementsByTagName("*");    // get all child elements
for (var i=0; i<all_childs.length; i++) 
    {
    if ( all_childs[i].hasAttribute("class") ) all_childs[i].className = ""; // or all_childs[i].removeAttribute("class")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to write some automated tests. Consider this: if you modify the UI content, you just might affect the behavior of something else on the page (e.g. some JS assuming those class-attribute values might stop functioning).

Alternatively, inject CSS (via STYLE or LINK) that changes the appearance and visibility of those elements (hint: `!important`). However, even this, theoretically, is not ideal solution, because like-JS (for example) might go bananas for the same reason.

I'm not experienced in testing webpages, but isn't the point of Selenium to automate behavior of a human user? In other words, maybe the best would be to write test-code to activate the menu the same way human-user would (mouseover, etc).